# Getting warning "getClientId should not be called while the view is being constructed."

Tags: jsf, trinidad

In my JSF application I have one JSP page which keeps generating a warning which *sometimes* gets rendered. In the log files I can see something like this:

```
WARNING: getClientId should not be called while the view is being constructed. 
         Component-ID: j_id18
```

The component which generates the warning looks like this:

```
<tr:panelCaptionGroup captionText="Jobs">
<tr:poll pollListener="#{jobBean.update}" id="poll" interval="#{msg.cfg_pollingInterval}" />
<tr:table allDetailsEnabled="true" partialTriggers="::poll ::groupFilter">
  <f:facet name="detailStamp" >
    <tr:table var="trg" value="#{subbean}" >
       ...stuff...
</tr:table>
  </f:facet>
  <tr:column>
    <h:panelGroup>
  <tr:commandLink  />
    </h:panelGroup>
  </tr:column>
  <tr:column />
</tr:table>
```

Could it be an issue with polling in the table?

I'm using Trinidad 2.0.0.
I've tried the option `org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CLIENT_ID_CACHING` in `web.xml` and I observe the behavior with all options ON, OFF and DEBUG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, there was a NPE occurring somewhere while creating a dropdown in the screen.
The code has been fixed, and the warning doesn't appear any more.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to refresh any parent programatically in a backing bean prior to ending up in this state.

Note, it looks like this message was added to java/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/component/UIXComponentBase.java in May 2010 at revision 942933 to prevent and NPE when clientId is null.

Comment: Nice research, do you have a link for that? How did you programmatically refresh the parents? Your answer may very well be valid, but please elaborate when you answer on a question!